# Julia equivalent of Matlab's pause?

Tags: julia

In Matlab, the function

```
pause(x)
```

Stops execution for `x` seconds. Is there something similar in Julia?

Comment: `sleep(seconds)`
Block the current task for a specified number of seconds. The minimum sleep time is 1 millisecond or input of 0.001.

Comment: Thanks @brauner, `sleep` does the job. Please post it below so I can accept.

Comment: of course. Happy to do so. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One method in `julia` is to use the `sleep()` function which takes the number of seconds as a parameter. The minimum number of time is 1 millisecond or an input of `0.001`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a serious answer, but I have a note-to-self from `julia v0.4` days to use the following to pause execution for `t` seconds:

```
f = t -> watch_file(".",t)
```

[Here's the current stable version documentation of `watch_file`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network/#Base.Filesystem.watch_file).

I have another similar note suggesting this:

```
f = t -> (b=time(); while b+t > time() end)
```

I have no earthly idea why either would be preferred method of pausing program execution vs. `sleep(x)`, perhaps someone could comment.

Comment: I compared accuracy for `sleep()` and `FileWatching.watch_file()` based `f` and it's comparable.

Comment: It seems that sleep is non-blocking. So that if you @spawn a function that calls sleep, it will allow other tasks to run once it starts to sleep. your 2nd note will not do that.